# my web app looks different on server and works perfectly on localhost

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, datatables, localhost

i'm using datatables with codeigniter 
and it looked like this on localhost 
[datatables on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTKfD.png)

and looked like this on server, i can't get the columns on the right side
even if i enabled scrollX 
[datatables on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPky0.png)

my java-script code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#tb').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "colReorder": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(roleURIUser()); ?>/leads/viewdata',
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">Rlfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "<?= locationPlugin('url'); ?>datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayStart ": 10,
            "aoColumns": [{
                    "mData": "name"
                }, {
                    "mData": "mobile"
                }, {
                    "mData": "phone"
                }, {
                    "mData": "branch"
                }, {
                    "mData": "code"
                }, {
                    "mData": "email"
                }, {
                    "mData": "university"
                }, {
                    "mData": "faculty"
                }, {
                    "mData": "address"
                }, {
                    "mData": "date_created"
                }, {
                    "mData": "status"
                }, {
                    "mData": "comment"
                }, {
                    "mData": "date_followup"
                }],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {"bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]},
                {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]},
                {"width": "30%", "aTargets": [11]}
            ],
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "<img src='<?= locationUpload('url'); ?>/ajax-loader.gif'>"
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
                //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            },
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax
                        ({
                            'dataType': 'json',
                            'type': 'GET',
                            'url': sSource,
                            'data': aoData,
                            'success': fnCallback
                        });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please state the relevant code and an example that replicates the problem you are experiencing

Comment: You should post your code and/or an minimal example.  This will help people trying to understand and/or reproduce your problem.

Comment: Check the network log in your web browser's console window. It seems like some assets (CSS/JS/images) might be missing on your server. It would also help to check for any JS errors.

Comment: i have added the java-script code
and there's no js errors

Answer (score 1):

Check the image path of button next to your name.(+) and (-) image path.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand well at all.

If the problem is that you can not get the data on the server, check your config data in application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "host";
$db['default']['username'] = "username";
$db['default']['password'] = "password";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```

If your CONECCION is correct, then the problem is in your model or your controller, eg

controller.php

```
function do_somthing(){
    $this->load->library('database');
    $this->load->model('model_file');

    $info = $this->model_file->get_data();

    var_dump($info);
}
```

model_file.php

```
function get_data(){
    return $this->db->get('table')->result();
}
```

Comment: that's not my problem, everything work fine 
it just not look good on server, and look perfect on localhost